# MPMoviePlayer and AVAudioRecorder

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, avaudiorecorder, mpmovieplayer

Has any one faced any issue with AVAudioRecorder behaving abnormally after video has been played back in an iOS app? I am using a moviePlayerViewController to play a stored movie file. After this if I try to record an audio, the AVAudioRecorder does not record, nor does it give any error message.
The record audio functionality is otherwise working fine.

Please help!
Thanks

Comment: Can you post some code which you have implmented.

Comment: Here is the link that solved my problem. Thanks! http://bit.ly/OHZuUt

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a AudioSession before prepareToRecord

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession =[AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
```

[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord  error:nil];
[audioSession setActive:YES  error:nil];